# How to limit version when building a package?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I have a Multi-Targeting project (`netstandard2.0` and `net461`).

When I collect the project, I get a package.

[image]

> How can I limit version? (=1.0.6)

I tried to do so Version="[1.0.6]", but then the project is not built

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <RepositoryUrl></RepositoryUrl>
    <Copyright>-</Copyright>
    <Description>-</Description>
    <Company>-</Company>
    <Authors>-</Authors>
    <PackageProjectUrl>-</PackageProjectUrl>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>OracleExtensions.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
    <Version>1.0.7</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.7.0</AssemblyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\PRB.OracleExtensions.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\PRB.OracleExtensions.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="licenses.licx" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="licenses.licx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Devart.Data" Version="5.0.1926" />
    <PackageReference Include="Devart.Data.Oracle" Version="9.5.502" />
    <PackageReference Include="Devart.Data.Linq" Version="4.8.1471" />
    <PackageReference Include="Devart.Data.Oracle.Linq" Version="4.8.1471" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.4.2" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PRB.Extensions\PRB.Extensions.csproj">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    <Reference Include="Devart.Data, Version=5.0.1926.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Devart\dotConnect\NET2\Devart.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Devart.Data.Linq, Version=4.8.1471.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Devart\dotConnect\NET2\Devart.Data.Linq.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Devart.Data.Oracle, Version=9.5.502.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Devart\dotConnect\NET2\Devart.Data.Oracle.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Devart.Data.Oracle.Linq, Version=4.8.1471.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Devart\dotConnect\NET2\Devart.Data.Oracle.Linq.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" Version="4.4.1" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" Version="4.0.0" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PRB.WcfExtensions\PRB.WcfExtensions.csproj">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PRB.Extensions\PRB.Extensions.csproj">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
    </ProjectReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to limit version when building a package?

This is a known issue about limiting version for `ProjectReference`. At this moment, [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) not support `ProjectReference`, so we could not upper version limit for `ProjectReference`,like we do on the `PackageReference`.

For the **known issue**, please check: [Allow an upper limit Version for ProjectReference references in nupkg from `dotnet pack` to support semver](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5556).

As a **workaround**, we could convert the `ProjectReference` to the `PackageReference`, then use `Version="[1.0.6]"` for the `PackageReference`.

**Detailed steps:**

1) Generate the nuget package for the project `PRB.Extensions` and `PRB.WcfExtensions`, get the package `PRB.Extensions.1.0.6.nupkg` and `PRB.WcfExtensions.1.0.0.nupkg`.

2) Set those two packages to a local feed, then install them to the project `PRB.OracleExtensions`, then you will got following code:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PRB.Extensions" Version="1.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

3) Set version limit to the `PackageReference`:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    <PackageReference Include="PRB.Extensions" Version="[1.0.6]" />
    <PackageReference Include="PRB.WcfExtensions" Version="[1.0.0]" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="PRB.Extensions" Version="[1.0.6]" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Note:** When you use `PackageReference` instead of `ProjectReference`, you should remove `ProjectReference` before you add the nuget package to the project `PRB.OracleExtensions`.

Comment: I suspected that there was no support. Thanks I will think.